# Multi WCF CallBack Interfaces on WPF

Tags: wcf

I have to communicate 2 WPF application.
To communicate, i am using a WCF windows service running on local machine.

When one of then calls a method on service, service calls back to other one. There is just one callback interface and all methods are written in it. But, 2 WPF apps are not using same callback methods. So, i am forced to implement unused methods.

So, I am tried to find if i can set 2 different and independent callback interfaces on service, but i couldn't. Is there any way to do it?

**UPDATE**

My sample code:

IDeviceCallBack

```
public interface ITestCallBack1
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Test1();
}

public interface ITestCallBack2
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Test2();
}

public interface IDeviceCallback : ITestCallBack1, ITestCallBack2
{ }
```

IDevice

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ITestCallBack1))]
public interface ITestContract1
{ }

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ITestCallBack2))]
public interface ITestContract2
{ }


[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IDeviceCallback))]
public interface IDevice : ITestContract1, ITestContract2
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Subscribe();

    [OperationContract]
    bool Unsubscribe();
}
```

What I want:
WPF1

```
[CallbackBehaviorAttribute(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public partial class MainWindow : Window, ITestCallBack1, IDisposable//,IDeviceCallBack
{
    private InstanceContext context;
    private DeviceClient deviceClient;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        context = new InstanceContext(this);
        deviceClient = new DeviceServiceReference.DeviceClient(context);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        deviceClient.Close();
    }

    public void Test1()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // Not Wanted
    //public void Test2()
    //{
    //    throw new NotImplementedException();
    //}
}
```

WPF2

```
[CallbackBehaviorAttribute(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public partial class MainWindow : Window, ITestCallBack2, IDisposable //,IDeviceCallBack
{
    private InstanceContext context;
    private DeviceClient deviceClient;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        context = new InstanceContext(this);
        deviceClient = new DeviceServiceReference.DeviceClient(context);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        deviceClient.Close();
    }

    // Not Wanted
    //public void Test1()
    //{
    //    throw new NotImplementedException();
    //}

    public void Test2()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think a service can only have a single callback interface.  What about splitting your service into two?  If they are doing two different conceptual operations it might make more sense anyway.  Maybe post a snippet of code to show what you are doing?

Comment: @user1039947 i post a snippet. You are right, i should. There will be so much messages, i don't want it to be.

Comment: Or, is there any way to do this? (except `private IntPtr WndProc`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not completely clear on your requirement here but I will take a shot at helping anyway...

So, you can have only a single callback interface per service in WCF which means you will need two services.  You can do some inheritance though so that you do not have to duplicate anything on your server.  Following is an example that I hope explains how to do it...

```
// A base interface for both services that contains the common methods
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Subscribe();

    [OperationContract]
    bool Unsubscribe();
}

// Service interface for service 1, using callback 1
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ITestCallBack1))]
public interface ITestContract1 : ITestService
{
}

// Callback interface for service 1
public interface ITestCallBack1
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Test1();
}

// Service interface for service 2, using callback 2
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ITestCallBack2))]
public interface ITestContract2 : ITestService
{
}

// Callback interface for service 2
public interface ITestCallBack2
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Test2();
}

// This is a base class that contains everything common to the two services
public abstract class TestServiceBase<T> : ITestService
{

    public bool Subscribe()
    {
        // Let's say that after subscribing we will wait for a bit
        // and call back (just an example)
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
                                         {
                                             Thread.Sleep(5000);
                                             RaiseCallback((T) o);
                                         },
                                     OperationContext
                                         .Current
                                         .GetCallbackChannel<T>());
        return true;
    }

    public bool Unsubscribe()
    {
        // Do whatever you need here
        return true;
    }

    // abstract method to raise the callback because the method names
    // are different for the two callback interfaces - notice the overriding
    // method does not need to do anything except call the correctly named method
    protected abstract void RaiseCallback(T callback);
}

// Concrete implementation of TestService1 - you can see that it
// only does whatever is specific for it
public class TestService1 : TestServiceBase<ITestCallBack1>, ITestContract1
{
    // Notice I get the callback1 interface to call the client
    protected override void RaiseCallback(ITestCallBack1 callback)
    {
        callback.Test1();
    }
}

// Concrete implementation of TestService2 - you can see that it
// only does whatever is specific for it
public class TestService2 : TestServiceBase<ITestCallBack2>, ITestContract2
{
    // Notice I get the callback2 interface to call the client
    protected override void RaiseCallback(ITestCallBack2 callback)
    {
       callback.Test2();
    }
}
```

Here is the configuration for the services:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="Demo.TestService1" behaviorConfiguration="NetTcpServiceBehavior">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9999/TestService1"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
     <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="Demo.ITestContract1" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBindingConfiguration"/>
     <endpoint address="mex" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" bindingConfiguration="MexBindingConfiguration"/>
    </service>
    <service name="Demo.TestService2" behaviorConfiguration="NetTcpServiceBehavior">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9999/TestService2"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="Demo.ITestContract2" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBindingConfiguration"/>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" bindingConfiguration="MexBindingConfiguration"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="NetTcpBindingConfiguration"
               maxConnections="5"
               portSharingEnabled="true">
        <security mode="None">
          <transport protectionLevel="None"/>      
        </security>
      </binding>
      <binding name="MexBindingConfiguration" portSharingEnabled="true">
        <security mode="None">
          <transport protectionLevel="None"/>    
        </security>
      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="NetTcpServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Then on the client you need a reference to the service that you are interested in the callback for (so your WPF 1 would reference /TestService1 and WPF 2 /TestService2).

Notice that you can put all the logic that is common to your two services in the TestServiceBase class - it takes the callback interface just so that it can call it.  In reality you may not need this - I do not know under what circumstances you are wishing to call back to the client

Comment: Thanks for your help @user1039947. I understand what you have tried, and that's wonderful. I haven't get time for try the code yet, possible it will work. But, there is a possible situation like that: wpf1 calls ITestContract1 method. Then, this sends callback firstly ITestCallBack2, secondly ITestCallBack1. (shortly, contact1 will send callback1 and callback2). Is it possible?

Comment: If you have one client that needs to handle two different callbacks then I would just have two methods on the callback interface.